# joining temporal tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am looking for better solutions to a fairly generic problem with temporal tables.

say we have

```sql
table_a (some_value int, date_from date, date_to date)
```

and a series of similar tables `table_b`, `table_c`, ...

the actual system is an HR system that tracks persons, contracts, assignments, salaries, ... all they are all dated in the way described above.

I need to join such tables (e.g. imagine getting all rows with the same `some_value`) and return the period for which such join is valid (that is all the rows overlap over such period).

with two tables it is easy (ignore `NULL` values for the time being)

```sql
select a.some_value, greatest(a.date_from, b.date_from) date_from, least(a.date_to, b.date_to) date_to
from table_a a join table_b b on a.some_value = b.some_value
where a.date_from < b.date_to and b.date_from < a.date_to
```

this become quadratically harder with more tables, because with three table (A, B, C) you need to check the overlap between A and B, B and C, C and A. with N tables this grows as N^2.

so I have written a pl/sql pipelined function (call it `dated_join`) that given two intervals it returns one row with the overlapping period or nothing if it doesn't overlap

so I can have for three tables

```sql
select a.some_value, period_b.date_from, period_b.date_to
from table_a a
join table_b b on a.some_value = b.some_value
join table(dated_join(a.date_from, a.date_to, b.date_from, b.date_to)) period_a
join table_c c on a.some_value = c.some_value
join table(dated_join(period_a.date_from, period_a.date_to, c.date_from, c.date_to)) period_b
```

this scales linearly to N values, because each period is joined only with the previous one and it carries forward the overlapping period.

question: is it possible to make this strategy work with `OUTER JOIN`s? I cannot find any half-decent solution.

is there anything in the SQL:2011 temporal extensions that would help with this?

thanks for your help

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to join multiple table so that they all overlap the same period then you can use `GREATEST` and `LEAST`:

```sql
SELECT t1.date_from AS t1_from,
       t2.date_from AS t2_from,
       t3.date_from AS t3_from,
       t4.date_from AS t4_from,
       t1.date_to   AS t1_to,
       t2.date_to   AS t2_to,
       t3.date_to   AS t3_to,
       t4.date_to   AS t4_to
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON (   t1.date_to   > t2.date_from
          AND t1.date_from < t2.date_to )
       INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON (   LEAST( t1.date_to, t2.date_to )        > t3.date_from
          AND GREATEST( t1.date_from, t2.date_from ) < t3.date_to )
       INNER JOIN table4 t4
       ON (   LEAST( t1.date_to, t2.date_to, t3.date_to )          > t4.date_from
          AND GREATEST( t1.date_from, t2.date_from, t3.date_from ) < t4.date_to );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( date_from, date_to ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-10', DATE '2020-02-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-15', DATE '2020-03-18' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( date_from, date_to ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-05', DATE '2020-01-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-09', DATE '2020-02-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-16', DATE '2020-03-18' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table3 ( date_from, date_to ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-09', DATE '2020-01-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-08', DATE '2020-02-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-15', DATE '2020-03-17' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table4 ( date_from, date_to ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-02', DATE '2020-01-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-08', DATE '2020-02-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-16', DATE '2020-03-19' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> T1_FROM   | T2_FROM   | T3_FROM   | T4_FROM   | T1_TO     | T2_TO     | T3_TO     | T4_TO    
> :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------
> 15-MAR-20 | 16-MAR-20 | 15-MAR-20 | 16-MAR-20 | 18-MAR-20 | 18-MAR-20 | 17-MAR-20 | 19-MAR-20
> 10-FEB-20 | 09-FEB-20 | 08-FEB-20 | 08-FEB-20 | 15-FEB-20 | 16-FEB-20 | 17-FEB-20 | 17-FEB-20
> 01-JAN-20 | 05-JAN-20 | 09-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 | 10-JAN-20 | 15-JAN-20 | 16-JAN-20 | 12-JAN-20
> ```

and, if you want it so that there is an overlap with any part of the ranges, then swap the `GREATEST` and `LEAST`:

```sql
SELECT t1.date_from AS t1_from,
       t2.date_from AS t2_from,
       t3.date_from AS t3_from,
       t4.date_from AS t4_from,
       t1.date_to   AS t1_to,
       t2.date_to   AS t2_to,
       t3.date_to   AS t3_to,
       t4.date_to   AS t4_to
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON (   t1.date_to   > t2.date_from
          AND t1.date_from < t2.date_to )
       INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON (   GREATEST( t1.date_to, t2.date_to )  > t3.date_from
          AND LEAST( t1.date_from, t2.date_from ) < t3.date_to )
       INNER JOIN table4 t4
       ON (   GREATEST( t1.date_to, t2.date_to, t3.date_to )    > t4.date_from
          AND LEAST( t1.date_from, t2.date_from, t3.date_from ) < t4.date_to );
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> T1_FROM   | T2_FROM   | T3_FROM   | T4_FROM   | T1_TO     | T2_TO     | T3_TO     | T4_TO    
> :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------
> 15-MAR-20 | 16-MAR-20 | 15-MAR-20 | 16-MAR-20 | 18-MAR-20 | 18-MAR-20 | 17-MAR-20 | 19-MAR-20
> 10-FEB-20 | 09-FEB-20 | 08-FEB-20 | 08-FEB-20 | 15-FEB-20 | 16-FEB-20 | 17-FEB-20 | 17-FEB-20
> 01-JAN-20 | 05-JAN-20 | 01-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 | 10-JAN-20 | 15-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 | 12-JAN-20
> 01-JAN-20 | 05-JAN-20 | 09-JAN-20 | 02-JAN-20 | 10-JAN-20 | 15-JAN-20 | 16-JAN-20 | 12-JAN-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d943a6fa12f109d9523bd5de7af2c689)*

Comment: excellent answer. I think this is a clean solution whose complexity is grows linearly. I didn't know about dbfiddle. Thanks.

Comment: actually, isn't that equivalent to ```FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON 1=1
       INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON 1=1
       INNER JOIN table4 t4
       ON (   LEAST( t1.date_to, t2.date_to, t3.date_to )          > t4.date_from
          AND GREATEST( t1.date_from, t2.date_from, t3.date_from ) < t4.date_to );```

Comment: @user103716 `INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON 1=1` is the same as `CROSS JOIN table2 t2`. I think it is the same but I am not certain and you would need to check the explain plan to see if it is more efficient to do the more restrictive filtered joins rather than using cross joins and a single filter condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all values from tables that overlap with the timeperiod, then you seem to want:

```
select *
from table_a a left join
     table_b b
     on b.date_from < a.date_to and
        b.date_to > a.date_from left join
     table_c c
     on c.date_from < a.date_to and
        c.date_to > a.date_from
where a.value = ?
```

I don't see any "quadratic" complexity.  Exactly the same join conditions are used for each new table.

Comment: for 2 tables you need 1 join. for 3 tables you need 3 joins. for 4 tables you need 6 joins (a-b, a-c, a-d, b-c, b-d, c-d). for N tables it's N * (N-1) / 2. I think your query misses the join between b and c. If A overlaps with B and with C, it does not guarantee that B overlaps with C.

Comment: @user103716 . . . I don't see that.  You should only care about overlaps with the first table.

Answer (score 0):

improving on the solution given above by @MT0 we can use a different overlap test

```sql
GREATEST(t1.date_from, t2.date_from) < LEAST(t1.date_to, t2.date_to)
```

and extend it to any number of tables

```sql
GREATEST(t1.date_from, t2.date_from, t3.date_from, t4.date_from, ...) 
< LEAST(t1.date_to, t2.date_to, t3.date_to, t4.date_to, ...)
```

the inner join can then be replaced by one single test

```sql
SELECT t1.date_from AS t1_from,
       t2.date_from AS t2_from,
       t3.date_from AS t3_from,
       t4.date_from AS t4_from,
       t1.date_to   AS t1_to,
       t2.date_to   AS t2_to,
       t3.date_to   AS t3_to,
       t4.date_to   AS t4_to
FROM   table1 t1
       CROSS JOIN table2 t2
       CROSS JOIN table3 t3
       CROSS JOIN table4 t4
WHERE
GREATEST(t1.date_from, t2.date_from, t3.date_from, t4.date_from) 
< LEAST(t1.date_to, t2.date_to, t3.date_to, t4.date_to);
```

while the outer join becomes

```sql
SELECT t1.date_from AS t1_from,
       t2.date_from AS t2_from,
       t3.date_from AS t3_from,
       t4.date_from AS t4_from,
       t1.date_to   AS t1_to,
       t2.date_to   AS t2_to,
       t3.date_to   AS t3_to,
       t4.date_to   AS t4_to
FROM   table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on 
greatest(t1.date_from, t2.date_from) < least(t1.date_to, t2.date_to)
left outer join table3 t3 on 
greatest(t1.date_from, t2.date_from, t3.date_from) < least(t1.date_to, t2.date_to, t3.date_to)
left outer join table4 t4 on 
greatest(t1.date_from, t2.date_from, t3.date_from, t4.date_from) < least(t1.date_to, t2.date_to, t3.date_to, t4.date_to);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e43b7c58208b7ea85af24ec0ec0ca4a7